# Simple MySQL join doesn't work

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

I'm trying to select comments and summary statistics about their corresponding votes. Not every comment has votes, and the ones that do can have more than 1 vote. Here's my query:

```
select
    `article-comments`.id,
    `article-comments`.user as user_id,
    concat(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) as name,
    users.job_title,
    users.company_name,
    avatar,
    `article-comments`.content,
    datediff(now(), `article-comments`.date_added) as diff,
    `article-comments`.date_added as date,
    count(`comment-votes`.id) as votes_count,
    sum(`comment-votes`.score) as votes_score
from
    `article-comments` left outer join `comment-votes` on `article-comments`.id = `comment-votes`.comment,
    users
where
    `article-comments`.status = 1
 && `article-comments`.article = $resource_id
 && `article-comments`.user = users.id
 && `comment-votes`.status = 1
order by
    `article-comments`.id asc
```

It works perfectly without the join, but only returns 1 row with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say it works perfectly, does it give you your desired results without the join?

Comment: It'd be easier to help if you simplified the query to isolate the problem - take out the unnecessary columns in the SELECT, and hardcode the values in the WHERE clause - what are $table and $resource_id ?

Comment: @Adam - Yes it does, minus the 2 summary statistics count() and sum()

Comment: @Mike - I did when I was trying to debug it, with no effect. I edited $table out of my original post, and $resource_id is the article ID.

Comment: (Unrelated to the question) don't use `&&`. Use `AND`

Comment: @ypercube - why? (it's a habit)

Comment: Because `&&` is not standard, it is used only in MySQL.

Comment: && is used in PHP, Perl, Javascript, and any other web language...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select
                `article-comments`.id,
                `article-comments`.user as user_id,
                concat(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) as name,
                users.job_title,
                users.company_name,
                avatar,
                `article-comments`.content,
                datediff(now(), `article-comments`.date_added) as diff,
                `article-comments`.date_added as date,
                count(`comment-votes`.id) as votes_count,
                sum(`comment-votes`.score) as votes_score
            from
                `article-comments` left join `comment-votes` on (`article-comments`.id = `comment-votes`.comment),
                users
            where
                `article-comments`.status = 1
             && `article-comments`.$table = $resource_id
             && `article-comments`.user = users.id
            order by
                `article-comments`.id asc
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still returning that same row :[

Comment: Using aggregate functions such as COUNT and SUM will result in what you see, a single row always. Think about the classic "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM atable" to get the number of rows in that table. You should use GROUP BY along with these functions to get the data you need. The default behavior of MySQL allows someone to refer fields that are not included in a GROUP BY statement, which leads to some uncertain results. Read this if you want to know more on the subject http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by .